# In MS Access 2010, can query parameters be entered for each unique record?

Tags: ms-access, parameters, ms-access-2010

I am working on a database where each unique record is for a different destination. Can you set up parameter fields to prompt for entry on each unique record or is it for the field as a whole?

Comment: Please share more info.  What does the record look like -- key, destination, and other fields.  On what values of destination would you want to change which other field entry?  Some specific values would help us understand.

Comment: For example, query runs and finds value "99" in field X for multiple values in field Y. When run, parameter entry should be prompted for each record where value "99" was found in field X.

X          Y          Parameter
99        2499     (entry prompted)
99        3299     (entry prompted)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short outline in english, that is not code and will not run, but does give the idea.  I am puzzled by "parameter fields", and also do not know what happens to the "prompt" data after it is entered.  This procedural outline might be expanded upon and detailed,  and then used as a basis for writing the actual code that will run.

```
myRecordset = run myQuery
while myRecordset <> EOF
    if myRecordset.Fields("X")  = "99" then
        Show record values for "X" and "Y" and emptyPrompt
    endif
    myRecordset.MoveNext
End while
```